# SQL Server 2008 - Linked Firebird Server - not working properly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc, firebird, linked-server

I have a SQL Server 2008. I have created an ODBC connection to a Firebird database using the `Firebird/InterBase(r) driver`.

The connection works ok.

Then I created a linked server in SQL Server 2008 using the `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC diver`.

Everything seems to work fine. I can pull data from tables using

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVERNAME, 'SELECT * FROM TABLENAME')
```

with success.

My problem is remote store procedure call. On the Firebird side there is a stored procedure that has one input parameter. Sometimes I get the result, but most of the time I get an error. I am not sure why it is happening, but I don't understand much from the error.

I call the procedure like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVERNAME, 'SELECT * FROM GET_DOCUMENT_S(05011002766916)'
```

Its either I get the result (1 row) or I get an error. For id 05011002766916i always get the result, but for some id I never get an result, even tho the Firebird admin claims that the same procedure call returns result normally on his client.

Here are the errors I am getting:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVERNAME" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM GET_DOCUMENT_S(04170200133A120)" for execution against OLE DB provider
>   "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVERNAME".

Or:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVERNAME" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVERNAME".

Can someone please explain what could be the issue, as currently I dont know if its a problem in ODBC, linked server or Firebird side...

Thank you.

Comment: Does the stored procedure include the `SUSPEND` keyword?

Comment: Marc thank you for the edit. Mark: I am not sure since i am not Firebird admin. They just provided me with the procedure name. Now they dont really care to help me out. I need to find the error or prove that the error is on their side. I cant even test if the result is really returned as they claim... how can i check for suspend keyword?

Comment: You need to look at the source of the stored procedure. If it contains SUSPEND it means it is a selectable stored procedure, which is different from a normal stored procedure. What happens if you execute this directly to Firebird (eg using an admintool like FlameRobin)?

Comment: What is the syntax to execute the above procedure in flamerobin client?

Comment: Just execute the select statement (`SELECT * FROM GET_DOCUMENT_S(05011002766916)`)

Comment: Thank you Mark. Yes, FlameRobin also throws exception (IBPP:SQLException) so it looks like it is a problem on the Firebird side. If you want you can write an anwser in the manner (install Flamerobin and check) and I will accept it.

Comment: You too can post @Mark's solution as an answer and accept it. In this way people will see immediately that the question is solved and doesn't need a solution anymore. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on Firebird side. I used Flamerobin client and it produced IBPP:SQLException